# wget to follow redirection?

Tags: php, cron, wget

I have to run php script using cron job. The script reload several times with different parameters. The script works well in browser but not in cron job using wget. I know cron job don't handle redirections, but it is reloading same page just with different parameters. Wondering if this is possible?
Currently I am using `wget www.hostname.com/script/abc.php?param`
It works well for only first page.

Comment: `wget` normally follows redirects. Why do you think it's different in cron jobs?

Comment: The script uses `window.location` with new parameters. Which is not working in cron job.

Comment: `wget` doesn't execute Javascript. You should be using HTTP redirects if you want `wget` to follow it.

Comment: Ok, let me try with 'header location'.

Comment: wget is not working with `header location` either.

Comment: You need to explain more clearly what your script is supposed to do and what it's doing instead.